# Tamper Data for Internet explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer

I'm looking for a good program that is like the Tamper Data add on for Mozilla Firefox, but a program that works for Internet Explorer.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: An enumeration of the features from Tamper Data that you hope to use in Internet Explorer would be good.

Comment: I can help you over to superuser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the features (and more) of Tamper Data for Firefox can be found in an HTTP proxy such as Burp, Paros, or WebScarab.  These programs will work with any browser that supports HTTP proxying, and give you the ability to modify GET or POST parameters, cookies, requests, and responses.  I use [Burp](http://portswigger.net/burp/) on a daily basis, and I find it very effective.

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler sounds like exactly what you're looking for
http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/